# How do I add a configurable as a related product and show it's options in Magento 2.1

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, configurable-product, related-products

I am using Magento 2.1.9 and I would like the customer to see related products on a product page that are configurable without navigating away from original product page. Meaning you can configure and add to cart straight from the related products block. Is this possible to do?

Comment: Have you found any solution on it ?